# Use case for SocketAsyncEventArgs.BufferList?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

Why would you use [SocketAsyncEventArgs.BufferList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs.bufferlist(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of Buffer?

Comment: The webpage you posted is old ~2010 and has not be updated in a while.  Not sure if it is still applicable.  The webpage states following : "that represents an array of data buffers to use with an asynchronous socket method".  A standard buffer is not a List and doesn't handle Async method.

Comment: @jdweng This is the documentation for the latest version of .NET and it is not deprecated. "A standard buffer...doesn't handle Async method" - that is incorrect.

Comment: Then why is under the other version pull-down Net 4.5 isn't listed?

Comment: because 4.5 is the *current* version